# How to add a row for subtotal from each group and then a final row of grand total of entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| Location | Student Name |
| --- | --- |
| D | Amy |
| D | Raj |
| E | Mitch |
| F | Poo |
| F | Mack |

I am trying to generate the following dataframe:

| Location | Student Name |
| --- | --- |
| D | Amy |
| D | Raj |
| Total Students at D | 2 |
| E | Mitch |
| Total Students at E | 1 |
| F | Poo |
| F | Mack |
| Total Students at F | 2 |
| Grand Total | 5 |

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will offer a solution without loops.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['D','D','E','F','F'],
                   'Student Name':['Amy', 'Raj', 'Mitch', 'Poo', 'Mack']})
df1 = df.groupby('Location', as_index = False).agg({'Student Name':'count'})
df1['Location'] = df1['Location'].apply(lambda row : row + 'Total' )
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_values(by = 'Location')
df2['Location'] = df2['Location'].apply(lambda x : 'Total Students at ' + x[:len(x)-len('Total')] if x.endswith('Total') else x)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.drop(['index'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df2 = df2.append({'Location' : 'Grand Total', 'Student Name' : df1['Student Name'].sum()}, ignore_index = True)
```

Output :

```
df2

               Location Student Name
0                     D          Amy
1                     D          Raj
2   Total Students at D            2
3                     E        Mitch
4   Total Students at E            1
5                     F          Poo
6                     F         Mack
7   Total Students at F            2
8           Grand Total            5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data, total = {"Location": [], "Student Name": []}, 0
for loc, g in df.groupby("Location"):
    for name in g["Student Name"]:
        data["Location"].append(loc)
        data["Student Name"].append(name)
    data["Location"].append("Total Students at {}".format(loc))
    data["Student Name"].append(len(g["Student Name"]))
    total += len(g["Student Name"])

data["Location"].append("Grand Total")
data["Student Name"].append(total)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
              Location Student Name
0                    D          Amy
1                    D          Raj
2  Total Students at D            2
3                    E        Mitch
4  Total Students at E            1
5                    F          Poo
6                    F         Mack
7  Total Students at F            2
8          Grand Total            5
```

Comment: Thanks lot. The implementation was seamless.